# Solr - search score and tf-idf vector from individual fields

Tags: solr

This is a fundamental question which I was unable to get from the solr help and other related Stackoverflow queries.

I have few hundred thousand documents which have 12 fields in them (to be indexed). All of these fields have text in them (each field can have varying length text in them - may be from 10 to 5000 characters). 
For e.g , lets say these fields are named A, B ..... L (12 in all)

Now, when I search for documents, my query comes from 3 fields. X1 , X2 and X3.
Now X1 (conceptually) closely matches with fields C, D , and E. X2 (conceptually) closely matches with fields F, G and J. And X3 is basically the same field as A.
But X1 and X2 should be searched for, all over the fields (including A). Just filtering against their conceptually matching fields will not do.

So when designing the schema, my only criterion is the ranking and the search.
I also want (can I ? ) get scores of my query against individual fields. Something like this

Query : X1 , Score against C , E and over all score (for all returned documents)

Query : X2 , Score against M , N , O and over all score (for all returned documents)

Query : X1 + X2 , Score against C , E, M, N and O, and over all score (for all returned documents)

The reason I want those individual scores is I want to further use those scores for ML algorithms to further reshuffle/fit the rankings against a training set.

I also want want the tf-idf vector components of X1 and X2 against C, E and M,N,O respectively.

Can anyone please let me know if this is possible ?